# count number of occurances of a particular object from the array list using java8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Let Say, am having an array list :

```
catalog id--->901
Catalog name --->series277
catalog id--->901
Catalog name --->series277
catalog id--->545
Catalog name --->series285
catalog id--->545
Catalog name --->series285
catalog id--->545
Catalog name --->series285
catalog id--->546
Catalog name --->series685
catalog id--->546
Catalog name --->series685
catalog id--->40962
Catalog name --->series19348
catalog id--->40962
Catalog name --->series19348
catalog id--->40962
Catalog name --->series19348
catalog id--->40962
```

From this list, i want to find the number of occurances like below.

```
catalog id--->901    -- 2
catalog id--->545    -- 3
catalog id--->546    -- 2
catalog id--->40962  -- 4
```

My goal is, based on the number of occurances of `id` i want to create a loop to iterate further.

Please find my java code for the Arraylist creation

```
List<Catalog> catalogList2 = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
for (SearchHit hit1 : searchHits2)
{
  sourceAsMap2 = hit1.getSourceAsMap();
  catalog2 = new Catalog();
  catalog2.setId(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap2.get("catalog_id")));
  catalog2.setCatalog_name(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap2.get("catalog_name")));
  catalogList2.add(catalog2);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Trying to implement the below case :

```
for(int i=0;i<catalogList2.size();i++) {

        // want to find the number of occurances for catalog.getId()
        //Then i want to create a loop based on the number of occurances of catalog id
        for(int i=0;i<catalog_id_occurances.size;i++)
        {
            //Have to do something.
        }

    }
```

Comment: you said "My goal is, based on the number of occurrences of id i want to create a loop to iterate further" are you trying to say that if occurrence of 901 is 2 times then you want to loop two times ?

Comment: @Lokesh - Yes, exactly.

Comment: Besides it's an obvious duplicate, it looks like no attempt was made to solve the problem. Sorry, but filling a source list is not enough to get a sensible answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with Streams:

```
catalogs.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId, Collectors.counting()));
```

Output:

```
jshell> catalogList.stream().collect(
   ...>                 Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId, Collectors.counting()));
$43 ==> {901=2, 545=3, 546=2, 40962=4}
```

--EDIT--

In case you want to manipulate the output further or want to print in some customer format you can use below:

```
catalogList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId, Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().map(p->"catalog id--->"+p.getKey()+"    -- "+p.getValue()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
catalog id--->901    -- 2
catalog id--->545    -- 3
catalog id--->546    -- 2
catalog id--->40962  -- 4
```

Comment: If you want to count occurences of only some interesting objects, e.g. with chosen IDs, use filter() before collect(): catalogs.stream().filter(c -> INTERESTING_IDS.constains(c.getId())).collect(...)

Comment: how can i print the `id` and its occurances.?

Comment: @Karthikeyan updated my answer

Comment: @AmanChhabra - I have update my question., am trying to create one more loop based on the number of occurances of `catalog_id` .

Comment: @Karthikeyan Yes you can do that, In my second solution if you just remove the last forEach and map, you will have a stream entries with key containing id and value containing its count

Comment: @AmanChhabra - as per your code, am also getting the result as per u shown. But am not sure., how can i iterate with number of occurances of IDs. I have raised a separate question for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515283/looping-based-on-the-number-of-occurances-of-an-object-id-availabe-in-arraylis

Comment: @Karthikeyan Posted my answer as well :)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515436/1262248