# Looping through item occurences with same property (catalog_id)

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have a `Catalog` bean with the following properties:

```
catalog_id
catalog_name
catalog_price
catalog_title
```

`catalog_id` is not unique, there can be multiple `Catalog` object with the same `id`.

Having a list of `Catalog` objects, I want to collect all with the same `id` and in a second for loop I want to loop with through the number of occurance of that `id`.

Let say :

```
catalogList2.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(p->"catalog id--->"+p.getKey()+"    -"+p.getValue()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

From the above code I am able to get the below output:

```
catalog id--->17553    -- 8
catalog id--->545    -- 8
catalog id--->546    -- 6
catalog id--->40962    -- 16
catalog id--->901    -- 12
```

But, after that I want to do like below : ( its just a structure I want to implement)

```
for(Catalog cat1:p.getKey()){

    for(int i=0;i<p.getValue();i++){

        System.out.println("Name -->"+cat1.get(i)));
        //Something i will do here.

    }

}
```

I am not sure how to implement this structure.

**Update**

Am getting the message in my eclipse `Lambda expression's parameter catalog cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.`

when am trying to add 2nd sysout :

```
 catalogList2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId))
    .forEach((id, catalogs) -> {
        System.out.println("Catalog id : " + id + " : " + catalogs.size());
        catalogs.forEach(catalog -> {
            System.out.println("Name -->"+catalog.getCatalog_attr_name());
            System.out.println("Value --->"+catalog.getCatalog_attr_value());
        });
    });
```

**Update 2**

Am getting this message in eclipse `Local variable catalog defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

at the line `String catalogName=catalog.getCatalog_name();  // getting error on this line`

Please find my code here ;

```
JSONObject jsonObj=null;
JSONArray respArray=new JSONArray();
catalogList2.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId))
.forEach((id, catalogs) -> {
    System.out.println("Catalog id : " + id + " : " + catalogs.size());
    String catalogName=catalog.getCatalog_name();  // getting error on this line
    String longDescriptionStr = catalogName.concat("_long_description");
    String descriptionStr = catalogName.concat("_description");
    jsonObj.put("catalog_id", id);
    catalogs.forEach(c -> {
        String longDescription=null;
        String description=null;
        String catalogAttrName = c.getCatalog_attr_name();
        if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogAttrName, longDescriptionStr)) {
             longDescription = c.getCatalog_attr_value();
        }
        if(StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(catalogAttrName, descriptionStr)) {
            description = c.getCatalog_attr_value();
        }
        jsonObj.put("description", description);
        jsonObj.put("longDescription", longDescription);

    });
    respArray.put(jsonObj);

});
System.out.println("Printing JSON Array --->"+respArray.toString());
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: Replacing `Collectors.counting()` by `Collectors.toList()` will give you map entries of `<String, List<Catalog>>` instead of `<String, Integer>`. Is that enough to get your problem solved? Otherwise, give us more detail on what your problem is.

Comment: @MalteHartwig or just remove the downstream collector.

Comment: @Aominè true, realized that when the answer was posted. Didn't think too much into it as the question is rather unclear on the actual goal of the collect.

Comment: @instinct how do you know if the attribute `catalog_id` is of type `int`

Comment: I mistakenly interpreted that. if the type is different, feel free to change it, however it is worth it to mention the type of the ID field in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupingBy` without a downstream collector will map the IDs to lists of the catalogs with those IDs. You can then ask the lists for their size to get the count and iterate through the lists to get each catalog:

```
catalogList2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId))
    .forEach((id, catalogs) -> {
        System.out.println("Catalog id : " + id + " : " + catalogs.size());
        catalogs.forEach(System.out::println);
    });
```

Comment: Its printing like this ` Catalog id : 17553 : 8
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@304e5f60
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@53d55f54
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@3bb87e2e
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@5e9f8a1a
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@1ce86bf6
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@65bea8c0
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@1d0ff357
 com.jci.vb2.searchengine.bean.Catalog@3f6265b6`.

Comment: @Karthikeyan override the `toString()` method on your `Catalog` class

Comment: from the inner loop., am trying to print like `catalog.getName()`, `catalog.getTitle()` something like this..

Comment: @Karthikeyan then replace `System.out::println` by `catalog -> System.out.println("whatever you want to print")`

Comment: seems like what the OP is after. +1. and @MalteHartwig the answer looks much better with your added explanation. ;-)

Comment: @Aominè yes for sure, i partly agree with you !

Comment: @MalteHartwig - am getting the message in eclipse like `Lambda expression's parameter catalog cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.`. When i trying to add 2nd sysout. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Karthikeyan you declared a variable named `catalog` somewhere in the outer scope (outside of your lambda `(catalog) -> {...}`)

Comment: @marsouf - am getting this message now from eclipse `Local variable catalog defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`. I have updated my question `Update2`

Comment: @Karthikeyan apparently, you have defined the `catalog` variable outside from the code segment you have shown in your second edit. Dump the code segment where you have defined the `catalog` variable, it must be effectively final meaning once you have set it to a value, you need not to reassign a new value again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
catalogList
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Catalog::getId))
.forEach((key,value)->{
    for(Catalog curValue:value)
        System.out.println("Name -->"+curValue.catalog_name);
    });
```

Output:

```
Name -->Catalog 2
Name -->Catalog 3
Name -->Catalog 4
Name -->Catalog 1
Name -->Catalog 7
Name -->Catalog 8
Name -->Catalog 9
Name -->Catalog 15
Name -->Catalog 16
Name -->Catalog 18
Name -->Catalog 19
Name -->Catalog 20
```

Comment: This will not give access to the `Catalog` objects of a certain ID because the `collect` only gives you the count.